Validating file paths to satisfy GitHub CodeQL's "Uncontrolled data used in path expression" alert
I'm writing functions for a Python package to register files from a file system to an SQL database, and GitHub's CodeQL has flagged that the file paths are a potential security risk.
I have constructed a basic validator to make sure that only file paths that exist and start with a given base path when resolved are accepted for subsequent processing. However, CodeQL still views this as being insufficient.
Is this a false positive, or can my validation check be further enhanced? Note that I use resolve so that I can get and compare the start of the file paths.
Example Code
# Python version: 3.9.19
# OS: GNU/Linux RHEL8 4.18.0-553.5.1.el8_10.x86_64
from pathlib import Path

# The storage path is defined internally by an environment variable; here is a placeholder
storage_path = Path("/path/to/where/files/are/stored")

# Define a function to validate the file path provided
def validate_file(file: Path) -> bool:
    file = Path(file) if isinstance(file, str) else file  # Pre-empt accidental string inputs
    file = file.resolve()  # Get full path for validation

    # Fail if file doesn't exist
    if not file.exists():
        return False

    # Use path to storage location as reference
    basepath = list(storage_path.parents)[-2]  # This can be made stricter eventually
    if str(file).startswith(str(basepath)):
        return True
    else:
        return False

# How it's used in the script
incoming_file = Path("some_file.txt")  # Can be partial path, or full path on system

if validate_file(incoming_file) is True:
    """
    Run code here to store the file in the database
    """
    return True
else:
    raise Exception("This file failed the validation check")


Firstly I'm not 100% sure that Path.resolve is seen by CodeQL as a sanitizing function - so that might be a problem. I use os.path.normpath.
The main problem from a CodeQL point of view is that you're not sanitizing incoming_file.  Yes you're validating it, and not using it if it is invalid, but CodeQL can't detect that.  CodeQL needs to see something like:
def sanitize(filepath):
    fullpath = os.path.normpath(filepath)
    if not fullpath.startswith(storage_path):
        raise Exception("not allowed")
    return fullpath

sanitized_file = sanitize(incoming_file)
# do something with the file or handle the exception


Otherwise I think your validation looks ok, although I would check that the path starts with the full storage path.

Thanks for the quick feedback! I'll try running your suggestion by the CodeQL check and get back to you regarding the result! :)

Hey, just wanted to let you know that your suggestion of switching over to os.path worked swimmingly. I was able to use fullpath = os.path.normpath(os.path.realpath(filepath) to read the fully resolved file path from the provided input, and performed a regex validation check on the string, which CodeQL was happy with. What was also interesting was CodeQL disapproving of the check I wrote to test if the file existed. It would appear that letting it fail naturally later on is safer, according to it.

Wow, if it accepts os.path.normpath and rejects Path.resolve, consider stopping using a tool that promotes old and inconvenient interfaces. It's a deficiency. pathlib was introduced specifically to make string-typed paths less common (and shorten the code significantly, improving readability). Falling back to os.path is a bad solution to non-existent problem "my linter complaints" - there are better ones (pick a better linter, silence/ignore this message, etc.). It's good to rewrite code to make it more obvious to the tools, but not at the cost of maintainability.

Ahhh, that's insightful to know. Since Path is meant to be the way forward in Python in this regard, would it be fair to raise this as a false positive and request for the developers to correct how they would flag this sort of error in the future?
